# How does one have the console.log or prompt occur after an interval

Tags: javascript

I am using `console.log()` in a simple program

```js
console.log("Welcome");
var name = prompt("What is your name?");
console.log("Hello" + name);
```

But the prompt occurs before the Welcome message.
Is there a way to have these messages in sequence or is there an alternative.

I want the Welcome message to occur before the prompt, but it that does not happen and the prompt comes before ruining the flow of the program.

Comment: The flow of the program is working correctly. The "render" phase of the browser process is interrupted by the `prompt()` method. Once the prompt method gives control back to the browser, then all of the output is produced at one time. You must prevent the prompt from occuring until after your initial output occurs.

Comment: Thanks Randy for the input, is there an alternative that you suggest that might be useful for inputting the users choice and for outputting like prompt() and console.log do but better and in a flow or order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to achieve what you're after is to use use a `Promise` with `async/await` which will resolve after `setTimeout` call is complete. This way you can make your own "sleep" like function and thus "pause" the program before prompting the user:

```js
const sleep = t => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res,t));

(async _ => {
  console.log("Welcome");
  await sleep(1); // sleep for 1 milisecond
  var name = prompt("What is your name?");
  console.log("Hello " + name);
})();
```

Alternatively, you could use `alert()` for your outputs instead of using `console.log()`:

```js
alert("Welcome");
var name = prompt("What is your name?");
alert("Hello " + name);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Nick! Is there an alternative to console.log or prompt that you recommend?

Comment: @jai__ I added an alternative using `alert`, you could go an make your own HTML interface for printing and getting user input - but that would require more work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple version:

```js
console.log("Welcome");
setTimeout(() => {
  var name = prompt("What is your name?");
  console.log("Hello " + name);
}, 0)
```

You simply have to move the prompt to the next tick.  `setTimeout` will do it.

Comment: Thanks for the input Scott! I use p5.js and I am unable to do this, is there a way to perform this is p5.js?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't even know what p5 is!

Comment: So what do you use for writing in JavaScript?

Comment: I don't really know what you're asking.  I write lots of JS, and I've never run across p5.  Why do you find it essential for writing JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution...

```js
const p = new Promise((resolve) => {
  console.log("Welcome");
  resolve();
});

p.then(() => {
  var name = prompt("What is your name?");
  console.log("Hello" + name);
});
```

Recommend against the use of timeouts as they are unreliable for this purpose. This code simply says "do this", then "do that" in sequence.

Comment: simpler than `setTimeout`?

Comment: @ScottSauyet -  Yes, `setTimeout()` provides no guarantee to the order of operation at all. If you get lucky it will work as expected. Over time it may not work in the future

Comment: But here it should work as similar to `nextTick` or `setImmediate`, putting the function on the event queue to run in the next loop.  This does not offer a guarantee of when it will run, but since `console.log` offers no guarantee of when it will render, we are in no worse shape than if we sequence `console.log` and `resolve`.